Can the transmutation of hydrogen to heavier isotopes be reversed without the loss of energy. This is transmutation, not fusion
In a high frequency plasma enriched with hydrogen, the transmutation to heavier H isotopes is;   (n=neutron. p=proton. e=electron. E=energy)
n + p = Deuterium + E out. D + p = Helium + E out. Deuterium + n =Tritium + E out.
Is there a reaction with n, e, p or other element that will return the heavier isotopes back to lighter isotopes without using the energy gained?

Are you looking for an endless cycle that produces more energy than it consumes?

Can you please put the "equations" in separate lines, or increase the space between them?

Another question, how do you separate fusion from transmutation? Are there mechanisms other than fusion to go from H to He? Aren't fusion and transmutation synonyms in this case?

Why do you need a "high frequency plasma" to obtain Deuterium and Tritium from hydrogen by adding neutrons to the nucleus?

The plasma is needed to produce controlled U.V.  Electrons from the cathode via photoelectric action. It also ionizes the hydrogen to give neg ion + e = p (proton)
